# One Frame clip sometime play continuously

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

A clip i have made consist of **1 frame** animation it work some time nice but sometime **it play continuously or sometime it takes much time to complete**. When it continuously play I have log its time it remains 0*(no progress even if it work fine then also it remain to 0)* while the actual length of this clip is **0.333354.**

what is the problem? I am pulling my hair why sometime works and sometime not.

```
   gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("StartWait");
   gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>()["StartWait"].speed = 25;
```

while checking in update it play continously or take more time then expected even the **speed** is high while **time remain to 0**.

```
 if (gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("StartWait")) {
            Debug.Log(gameObject.name.Split('_')[1] + " startWait playing while speed :"
                + gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>()["StartWait"].speed + " and time :"
                + gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>()["StartWait"].time);

        }
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Unity3d. But in classic c#  [floating point deviations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) might be the cause of your trouble as you are working with very precise numbers at a 'very high' speed.

Comment: if set speed to 0 then it also not working sometime correctly

Comment: How do you check if a game object is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were associated with the culling of animation object. Animated object were far away from the view-port of my camera thats why animation were playing continuously.

When animation culling type selected to  [**BasedOnRenderers**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCullingType.BasedOnRenderers.html) then Animation become disabled.
For more info refer to question [Animation clip taking unexpectedly long time to finish](http://Animation%20clip%20taking%20unexpectedly%20long%20time%20to%20finish).